# CDN that supports custom SSL over custom domain

Tags: ssl, https, cdn

SSL is the biggest problem:
S3/Cloudfront doesnt support it.
Rackspace CloudFiles just told me they will support it in Q2 2011.
MaxCDN told me its $299 setup fee and a $299 monthly fee.

Based on MaxCDN i don't even want to try to ask edgecast or similar CDNs.

Does anyone know about a good solution? I think Softlayer does support custom SSL but i couldnt find it in the interface.

Thanks!

Comment: Just checked MaxCDN they now only charge $24.95

Answer (score 2):

Cachecentric.com is the cheapest i've seen for SSL, here is their ticket response:

Comment By: CacheCentric
Our nodes do support SSL, but there's additional charges associated with this:
1) Comodo SSL certificate registration is US$88/year (or US$187 per 3 years). You can also byo certificate for which we charge a one-time $10 install fee whenevr we need to install or update this.
2) There is a monthly fee of US$5 per month per serving location. If you give me an idea of the geographical profile of your traffic, and how much you're looking to spend, I can give you a list of serving nodes that would be most beneficial to choose.

They support reverse proxy also, which is useful...

Answer (score 1):

You need to separately assess your needs in *a)* serving content over SSL, and *b)* having a 'vanity URL' or custom domain as you write (i.e. `https://cdn.yourdomain.com`).

There are plenty of cheaper CDN providers who will do SSL on their own domain name, i.e. something like `https://<accountid>.cdncompany.com`.

A CDN typically has quite many web nodes (webservers), perhaps in separate clusters. When serving HTTPS, each of the webnodes that can be hit with a request for your content *must* have the certificate installed. That's an essential part of the authentication that SSL provides. Thus the handling all these customer certificates leads to a fair amount of work for the CDN provider, and that tends to be reflected in the price...

Bottom line, I doubt you will find SSL with vanity domains much cheaper than what MaxCDN is quoting you. You *could* try looking through all the dedicated re-sellers of established CDNs like [Akamai](http://www.akamai.com/html/partners/reseller.html), [EdgeCast](http://www.edgecast.com/company/partners/), [CDNetworks](http://www.us.cdnetworks.com/) et cetera. It might yield something, but it will likely take some time.